# How to convert a dict of `key: list` pairs into a list of tuples?

Tags: python, algorithm

What is the best way to convert `l1` into `l2`?

```
 l1 = {1: [],  
       2: ["tag1", "tag2"],
       3: ["tag2"])

 l2 = [(2, "tag1"), 
       (2, "tag2"),
       (3, "tag2")]
```

We are trying to find all key-value combos, but ignoring empty ones.

E.g.

`1: []` -> nothing (as there are no pairs)

`2: ["tag1", "tag2"]` -> `[(2, "tag1"), (2, "tag2")`]

`3: ["tag2"]` -> `[(3, "tag2")]`

And then join all of it into a single list.

Comment: Please explain how `l1` is turned into `l2`, because I honestly don't have the faintest idea...

Comment: @Aran-Fey Updated the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

do you mean that?

```
[(key, value) for key, values in l1.items() for value in values]
```

that results in

```
[(2, 'tag1'), (2, 'tag2'), (3, 'tag2')]
```

(where is your `'tag3'` from?)

Comment: Apologies, fixed the question, and yes, but is there a faster way using itertools etc?

Comment: why (and how) would you want to use itertools? `dict_items` is lazy as well; memory-wise there is nothing to gain.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job;

```
l1 = {1: [],  
      2: ["tag1", "tag2"],
      3: ["tag2"])

l2 = []
for key, values in l1.items():
    new_values = []
    for value in values:
        new_values.append(value)
    l2.append(tuple(new_values))


>>> l2
[(2, "tag1"), (2, "tag2"), (3, "tag2")]
```